# Objective - C - UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know that this question have been asked so many times but unfortunately non of the solutions in those questions worked for me.

Here are some of the things I tried:

making sure that `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is not returning `0`
making sure that `numberOfRowsInSection` is not returning `0`.
insuring that reloadData is being called on the main thread by using `performSelectorOnMainThread` as shown below:

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]
```

setting the delegate :

```
 self.tableView.dataSource = self; self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

making sure that tableview background color was changed.

making sure that tableview frame was adjustable.

But `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method never called

Please find the code:

UITableView *tableView;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,480) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView]
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 3;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = "test";
    return cell;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return 44;

}
```

If you have any idea what to do, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: are you estabilish the connection in connection inspector

Comment: where are you setting the delegate and datasource in viewDidload ?

Comment: Anbu, i have created the tableview programmatically.

Comment: Priyal, Yes, I have already tableview implement the same.

Comment: Can you add your relevant code ?

Comment: @arunkumar pandian What it says in error log?

Comment: Anbu, Priyal please check the code.

Comment: are you added these lines in your vc, `<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`

Comment: Tushar, No errors but cellrowindexpath method not called

Comment: Anbu, its already added

Comment: Check once what Karthik suggested.

Comment: Have you added breakpoint and tested?

Comment: Tushar already checked and but its not works.

Comment: Are you sure you call `reloadData` ? Try adding it in the end of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Tushar, yeah break point and logs implemented but no improvements.

Comment: Michael, I have consuming the web service, when i getting the value from service i will reload the tableview.

Comment: better atach your project

Comment: You are creating table object in viewDidLoad as local and accessing it in your service response, how?

Comment: Haripal , I have created the tableview as globally only i here i wrongly mentioned i will correct it.

Comment: `UITableView *tableView` : That's a local var. I don't think it's `self.tableView`.

Comment: what the controller type ? its viewcontroller or tableview controller ?

Comment: @arunkumar pandian : Have a look at my answer :)

Comment: Show your header file.

Comment: pawn - viewcontroller

Comment: Actually your code is fine. I tested it and it works.

Comment: There are some missing ; and @ characters in the code, but fix that and it works. Not sure why it not working at your end.

Comment: @arunkumar pandian add your header file code

Comment: Did you assign your class to the `UIViewController` in the storyboard?

Comment: Rikh - NO its not in storyboard. Its xib.

Answer (score 1):

You created the tableView added it as subView to your ViewController's view in ViewDidLoad() which is fine :) But where are you calling reload Data on tableView buddy :)

Add

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,480) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView]
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

It will work like a charm :)

Comment: Why would reloadData be necessary?

Answer (score 0):

just uninstall app from simulator and run again. sometimes its not work.

Comment: Nearly 10 times did the same and clean build both simulator and device. But its won't work.

Comment: your viewdidload code put into ViewDIDAppeer. may be self not assign to delegate and datasource.

Answer (score 0):

you have to delegate and datasource Protocol to view controller

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**

```
@interface yourController ()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```

**Second**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];



self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,480) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

[self reloadData]; //call your webservice here
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView]
[self.tableView reloadData]; //most imp
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return yourArray.count; //your array which is get from webservice

}
```